# Handling outdated dependencies in Gerrit

Tags: git, version-control, gerrit

I have a review change in Merge Pending state. Change depends on another change that is outdated. Dependency has a newer version that is already merged.

I tried to use rebase button to rebase pending change that was not successful, rebasing caused conflict. So I decided to fetch pending change to local repository and rebase it to master. I resolved conflict.

After that I wanted to push it back. I got error message:

```
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (change 166 closed)
```

Change 166 is the dependecy. So I'm not able to push back rebased version.

What is the approppriate method to get rid of outdated dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

Seems you've rebased CL#166 as well and trying to push these changes.

Rebase you change again and use
`git rebase ... -i`
to pick the only commits you need (ie remove the line with 166).